# Google Sheet - How to combine different cells with specific condition into one column

Tags: google-sheets

How do I combine those highlighted cells in one column? The highlighted cell is based one rule condition that contains a slash.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below formula-

```
=BYROW(B1:INDEX(F:F,INDEX(MAX((IF(B:F<>"",ROW(B:F),0))))),LAMBDA(x,JOIN(", ",FILTER(x,INDEX(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("/",x)))))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(REGEXMATCH(B:F; "\/"); B:F; ));;9^9))))
```

[image]